# Highstock cant click on scatter point with line series

Tags: highcharts

I want to register a click event with a point on a scatter series. This works when there are no other series displayed on the chart. However, when a line series is displayed i cannot get the click to occur on the scatter series. It only registers on the line series. This happens no matter what order i add the series to the chart. How can i register a click event on a scatter point in this case?

I have an example of the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/scottmlaplante/AfNzC/1/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    navigator:{
        baseSeries:1  
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function(event) {
                        alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y + event.point.series.name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [
        {
        type: "scatter",
        name: "scatter series",
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    },
        {
        type: "line",
        name:"line series",
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recognise which series point is clickec by checking index of series.

```
if(this.series.index==1)
                        alert('scatter');
                    else
                        alert('line')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scottmlaplante/AfNzC/1/

Comment: According to this answer its not recognizing the series i clicked on, instead its just going to print 'scatter' even though i clicked on line. Here, index 1 is the line series. How can i get the event to recognize that i clicked on the scatter point?